# CHECKOUT stream event failing in Sitecore CDP and Personalize if ADD event was triggered with different browserId

Tags: personalization, cdp

We have `website` and `mobile app`, both connected to **Sitecore CDP+Personalize** by using *Stream API*.

How to deal with the situation when user identified and added a product to cart through the website, then opened the mobile app *(identified with the same account)* and complete checkout *(or vise versa)*?

There are two **opened sessions** in the guest account: **WEB** with it`s own *browserId* and **MOBILE_APP** with different *browserId*. *(endpoints, point of sale, product ids, reference ids are the same)*.

It seems that CDP doesn't know how to place an order if some **ADD** events came from another device session.
[image][image]
[image]

**UPDATE**: all works fine if I send the same **browserId** from both devices *(in this case both sessions are merged in one single session)*, but it is impossible to have the same **browserId** on all devices by using *Stream API*.

Comment: Did you try to create an IDENTITY event first before your ADD one? It should help to merge different sessions from multiple devices together

Comment: yes, there are IDENTITY events in both sessions, you can see it on the screenshots.

Comment: Great, when Sitecore Personalize receives an IDENTITY event it runs a linking algorithm in an attempt to match guest data from other sessions based on your organisation's identity rules. What unique identifier do you use to identify a guest as a customer - browser reference or email address? https://doc.sitecore.com/personalize/en/users/sitecore-personalize/view-your-organization-s-identity-rules.html

Comment: Email address as you can see on the screenshot. Problem is not with IDENTITY, problem is with sessions from different channels.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore CDP and Personalize does not support cross session orders *(as there's no way without the session ID link to make sure the ADD events correspond to the CONFIRM)*.

Possible workaround *(thanks to Derek Fahey)*:

You can have logic that on login if items in the basket to resend the **ADD** events. This would mean the **MOBILE_APP** session would have all needed to complete the order.

For the **WEB** session then if you have abandoned trigger setup this will become an abandoned session *(technically correct)* but you can add logic to the abandoned experience to not trigger if there is another session open for **the same guest**, this is possible with a condition.